# Is Java for server runtimes like JBoss EAP / Wildfly still free to use?

Tags: java, licensing, oracle

With Oracle starting to collect license fees from different customers for using Java SE I've asked myself if the usage with a server runtime is still free. I'm no lawyer and all these licenses are more confusing than ever. There are BCL, GPL and others.

As far as I read this the use of Java for software development and desktop / server systems is free. License fees seem to relate to the use of Java in embedded devices and some (which?) parts of Java SE – not the runtime itself.

**Is there anything we have to check for license related issues with Oracle when running a JavaEE application in a server environment?**

We mainly use JBoss EAP which we licensed to Red Hat (we are Red Hat partner). We also use 3rd party frameworks like iText with separate licenses. But do we need some commercial license for using the Java runtime with our application servers?

Some (german) references:

- http://t3n.de/news/java-lizenzen-oracle-rechnungen-778411/
- http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Java-SE-Oracle-will-angeblich-kassieren-3574258.html

Edit : add english reference

- http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/16/oracle_targets_java_users_non_compliance/

Comment: From what i have understood, no it's only embedded device (mobile, handheld, ...).  So unless you run JBoss on a mobile you should be fine. However I know there are some component like a Windows Installer for Enterprise which is under license while it's been used to install some components that aren't targetted by the licence. Which mean you have not nly to check what do you use, but how they get installed... what a pain!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not [provide support for tools or products](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-here). These questions are best directed toward the customer support channels for the product.

Comment: Hmm... so I'll move to Open Source... which Java is in its core. We'll see.

Comment: FF http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4863/6998